# How does Fairy Tail's strongest team get back to Earth Land the second time?

Tags: fairy-tail

In *Fairy Tail: 100 Years Quest*, Natsu, Lucy, Erza, Gray, Happy, Carla, and Wendy all go to Edolas again. How do they get back to Earth Land?

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 67:

> They devise a plan to get back to Earth Land with the help of a dimension-travelling Elentearean Exceed (Elentear is another parallel dimension, a magical one, unlike Edolas) and by consuming the last of the X-Balls in Edolas ([X-Ball](https://fairytail.fandom.com/wiki/X-Balls) is a medicine that allows denizens of magical dimensions to retain their natural ability to produce magic while in Edolas, see Fairy Tail chapter 180).

Chapter 68:

> The plan is disrupted by Dragon Goddess Selene, who decides to teleport them to Elentear for her own amusement.

Chapter 89:

> Eventually they'll come back to Earth Land from Elentear with the help of the local mages.